# One host, two domains, two websites

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

So I want add second domain. I have website that uses domain1.com, but I want to add domain2.com which will show page from domain1.com/domain2_web/

I added domain at cpanel, but when I am going to domain2.com it redirects to domain1.com/domain2_web/

Is it possible to show domain2 website using only domain2.com ?

Answer (score 0):

If you access to the raw Apache .conf file, you can set up a virtual host that has a seperate DocumentRoot.

```
<VirtualHost domain2.com:80>
    DocumentRoot .../domain2/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: But if I dont have access? I am using hostpapa hosting

Comment: check with them. @bobbybee's suggestion assumes you have root access. If you don't have root access, you might have to open a ticket.